# button trigger event dont work for border?

Tags: c#, xaml

I search a lot about how to create a template for button in wpf for avoid or override default mouse over event and i create my own template ( with help of others codes ) but my codes dont work probably. i want to change background color and change border appreance but border trigger dont work. please check my codes and guide me to fix it thanks.

```
        <Button x:Name="AccountBtn" Width="250" Height="100" Margin="5 5 5 5" >
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border Name="Myborder" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1" BorderBrush="#EDEDED" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2 2 2 2"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Try to add `Background="Transparent"` to the button. Did it help?

Comment: i set it transparent but it didn't work.

Comment: i don't have any problem with background change trigger i have problem with border trigger in line 10 to 15. it don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper code would be the following

```
<Button x:Name="AccountBtn" Width="250" Height="100" Margin="5 5 5 5" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EDEDED"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="Myborder"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2 2 2 2"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

The problem with your code is not that the trigger isn't working. The trigger is working as it should, but the values of `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties are ignored in your template!

So I changed the code in such a way that

- the values of `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` are taken from the `Button`'s properties,
- the initial values are set in the style, and
- (optional) moved the triggers from the control template directly to the style.

That's all!

Comment: but on your code i still have my problem and its default color change of mouseover event

Comment: @imanking: I'm getting this behaviour: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqXrx.gif — is it not what you expect?